# Get 3 maximum values in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table in database that includes discount of products in percentage.
I want to get 3 maximum discount products. 
So if the table name is products.

linq query??

Need help. Thanx in Advance

[image]

Comment: _"linq query??"_ what have you tried? What is the desired result at all? What means _"I want to get 3 maximum discount products"_?

Comment: I am already getting answers to my question. It wasn't that much unclear. And a "down", I don't think it was necessary.

Comment: I have not downvoted it, but it was pretty unclear. For example, it was unclear if you want to group by products and take only three rows per group. You've just shown a screenshot and asked for code (`OrderBy(..).Take(3)` is also  fairly obvious imho). I guess that  was the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get your products ordered by the discount then take the first 3 items:

```
var topDiscounts = (from p in db.Products
                    orderby p.Discount descending
                    select p).Take(3);
```

Comment: oh.. This was simple. How could I miss such a thing. Thanx anyways

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
var query = deviceInfo.OrderByDescending(x => x.Discount).Take(3);
```